# How to close the connection after closing the cursor in try-except block?

Tags: python, mysql, lambda, rds

I am doing the code in Lambda function(Python 3.6) using RDS instance. The problem is if I don't do conn.close() occurs an increase in the number of connections in RDS. That will lead to errors afterward in API response[Internal server error].

Thing is we tried in finally block but not getting a proper output which is given below.

```py
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, port=3268, connect_timeout=30)
except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
    sys.exit()
def handler(event, context):
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
           cur.execute('SELECT * from OrderMaster')
           cur.close()
           return {'statusCode':200,"headers":{"access-control-allow-origin":"{}".format(headers)},"body":json.dumps(out)}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("error")
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: use the conn in handler function as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a reason to open the connection outside of your handler function but close it inside of it.
Open the connection using the with statement inside of your handler function.

```
def handler(event, context):
    try:
        with pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, port=3268, connect_timeout=30) as conn
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
               cur.execute('SELECT * from OrderMaster')
               return {'statusCode':200,"headers":{"access-control-allow-origin":"{}".format(headers)},"body":json.dumps(out)}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("error")
```

You also don't need to close your cursor because your with statement does that for you. That goes also for the connection.

Comment: I did as per your statements. Getting one error - ["'Cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'"] can you help to resolve it?

Comment: can you append your new code to your question please

Comment: Thank you with your help we were able to solve problem and did below proper code. @Florian H

Answer (score 2):

```
def handler(event, context):
    try:
       with pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, port=3268, connect_timeout=30) as cur:
          cur.execute('SELECT * from OrderMaster')
          return {'statusCode':200,"headers":{"access-control-allow-origin":"{}".format(headers)},"body":json.dumps(out)}
    except Exception as e:
       logger.error("error") 
    finally: 
       cur.close()
```